# How to wrangle JSON data into arrays of unknown name

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to use Chart.js to display unknown JSON data (The only part of the data I *do* know is that it will contain "time").

I have several datasets, so how do I get data from these formats...:

Dataset 1:

```
dataset1 = [ { "time": "2017-03-02 09:00", "volts": 10, "amps": 4.5 },{ "time": "2017-03-02 09:10", "volts": 9.87, "amps": 4.15 }, ...]
```

Dataset 2:

```
dataset2 = [ { "level": 1.23, "time": "2017-03-02 09:00", "volts": 3.5 }, { "level": 1.56, "time": "2017-03-02 09:10", "volts": 3.6 }, ...]
```

...to this format (for dataset1):

```
data[ "time" ]  = [ "2017-03-02 09:00", "2017-03-02 09:10", ...]
data[ "volts" ] = [ 10, 9.87 ...]
data[ "amps" ]  = [ 4.5, 4.15 ...]
```

...or this format (for dataset2):

```
data[ "time" ]  = [ "2017-03-02 09:00", "2017-03-02 09:10", ...]
data[ "level" ] = [ 1.23, 1.56 ...]
data[ "volts" ] = [ 3.5, 3.6 ...]
```

I don't know ahead of time what the keys (e.g. volts, amps, level) are going to be, so I'm not able to declare any arrays to push into.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: You could use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of the keys that the object has, although I don't know how supported it is. An example call would be `Object.keys(dataset1[0])` which would return `["time", "volts", "amps"]`

Comment: @George: I'll take a look at that now. Thanks for the swift response :-)

Comment: Well, I didn't know about Object.keys ( or Object.values or Object.entries - interesting) however I still can't see how to create the data[ xxx ] arrays :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using some dynamic arrays:

```
var dataset1 = [ { "time": "2017-03-02 09:00", "volts": 10, "amps": 4.5 },{ "time": "2017-03-02 09:10", "volts": 9.87, "amps": 4.15 }];
var dataset2 = [ { "level": 1.23, "time": "2017-03-02 09:00", "volts": 3.5 }, { "level": 1.56, "time": "2017-03-02 09:10", "volts": 3.6 }];
var data = [];
var datasets = [dataset1,dataset2];
for (var i in datasets) {
  var dataset = datasets[i];
  for (var j in dataset) {
    var d = dataset[j];
    for (var k in d) {
      if (!data[k]) data[k] = [];
      data[k].push(d[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/zhuxz2z6/1/